# Page numbering after titlepage

Tags: titles, page-numbering, fancyhdr, import

I am writing a small booklet for my elective using `\documentclass{abstract}`, and creating a separate `titlepage.tex`, then inserting it with `\import{./}{titlepage.tex}`. There are no page numbers on the titlepage itself, but after that, the page numbering starts from 2. How can I make the page numbering start from 1?
I tried using the `\thispagestyle{empty}` function in the titlepage environment, but it didn't work.

So, my `main.tex` looks like:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside]{article}

...

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\import{./}{titlepage.tex}

...

\end{document}
```